# Realm returning wrong results

Tags: android, realm

I receive from the server a list of objects. Each Object has many to many relationships with other objects, I save the server response to realm and everything looks fine on the realm browser. But when i call a find All on this object, some children come with the wrong values.
Example:

JSON Response:

```
    [{
        "id": 1127219,
        "products": [{
            "name": "product 1",
            "id": "519_1246"
        }, {
            "name": "product 2",
            "id": "519_1791"
        }],
        "steps": [{
            "action": "go_store",
            "location": {
                "id": 519,
                "lat": "4.675863000000",
                "lng": "-74.053015000000"
            },
            "id": "go_store-1127219"
        }, {
            "action": "take_product",
            "location": null,
            "id": "take_product-1127219"
        }, {
            "action": "go_home",
            "location": {
                "id": 367368,
                "lat": "4.679032500000",
                "lng": "-74.055361700000"
            },
            "id": "go_home-1127219"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 1127333,
        "products": [{
            "name": "Bebidas Starbucks",
            "id": "10000349_90220"
        }],
        "steps": [{
            "action": "take_product",
            "location": null,
            "id": "take_product-1127333"
        }, {
            "action": "go_home",
            "location": {
                "id": 367368,
                "lat": "4.679032500000",
                "lng": "-74.055361700000"
            },
            "id": "go_home-1127333"
        }]
    }]
```

RealmObjects:

```
       Order extends RealmObject {
             @PrimaryKey int id;
             RealmList<Product> products;
             RealmList<Step> steps;
        }

        Product extends RealmObject {
            @PrimaryKey int id;
            String name;
        }
        Step extends RealmObject {
             @PrimaryKey int id;
             RealmList<Position> position;
        }
        Position extends RealmObject {
             @PrimaryKey int id;
             double lat, lng;
        }
```

Rx

```
public Observable<List> getAll(Class clazz) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Observable o = Observable.just(mRealm.copyFromRealm(mRealm.where(clazz).findAll()));
        mRealm.closeRealm();
        return o;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

public Observable<?> putAll(@NonNull JSONArray jsonArray, String idColumnName, @NonNull Class dataClass) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        try {
            updateJsonArrayWithIdValue(jsonArray, idColumnName, dataClass);
        } catch(@NonNull JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        executeWriteOperationInRealm(mRealm, () -> mRealm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(dataClass, jsonArray));
        mRealm.close();
        return Observable.just(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}

@NonNull
private JSONArray updateJsonArrayWithIdValue(@NonNull JSONArray jsonArray, @Nullable String idColumnName, Class dataClass)
        throws JSONException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if(idColumnName == null || idColumnName.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(mContext.getString(R.string.no_id));
    }
    for(int i = 0, length = jsonArray.length(); i < length; i++) {
        if(jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
            updateJsonObjectWithIdValue(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i), idColumnName, dataClass);
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}

@NonNull
private JSONObject updateJsonObjectWithIdValue(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject, @Nullable String idColumnName, Class dataClass)
        throws JSONException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if(idColumnName == null || idColumnName.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(mContext.getString(R.string.no_id));
    }
    if(jsonObject.getInt(idColumnName) == 0) {
        jsonObject.put(idColumnName, Utils.getNextId(dataClass, idColumnName));
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

private void executeWriteOperationInRealm(@NonNull Realm realm, @NonNull Executor executor) {
    if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
    realm.beginTransaction();
    executor.run();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

So i receive a list of 2 orders, each having its own products and steps. Using the debugger and the realm browser everything seems to be saved fine, but when i `getAll();` Teh response is both orders with the correct products but both have the same steps, instead of having their respective steps. All the ids values come from the server. Help me please i have been stuck in this for a while now. thanks in advance

Comment: What thread is this on? More importantly, can you share the JSON response? And maybe the transaction code?

Comment: I have updated the question with all the data you requested

Comment: Now I'm only curious about how you **save** it to the Realm

Comment: Hahah, done. :)

Comment: https://github.com/Zeyad-37/GenericUseCase/blob/master/DataAccessLayer/src/main/java/com/zeyad/genericusecase/data/db/RealmManager.java
This is my RealmManager. This is my open source lib that i am using at work.

Comment: Your actual **library** code creates unclosed Realm instances that create version retention on thread pools, such as the io scheduler. I also think this solution is somewhat overcomplicated and also inconsistent (some calls return managed, some unmanaged results).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127410/discussion-between-zeyad-gasser-and-epicpandaforce).